# How to convert any video to 3GP?

Tags: video, conversion, 3gp

How do I convert video (of any format) to 3GP, so that I can play it on my cellphone?

(The OS is Windows XP.)

Comment: Do note that the video format is called "3GP", the 3rd Generation Partnership Project (3GPP) is a collaboration between groups of telecommunications associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a fair bit of conversion when I was using the early N-Series Nokia phones with [3GP Converter](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/3GP_Converter). It's very simple to use basically drag and drop.

Just a general tip too, I find that [videohelp.com](http://www.videohelp.com/) is very useful for links and guides to using conversion software.

Answer (score 2):

FFMpeg will convert almost anything to almost anything else, including 3GP.

Ready-built Windows versions are available, e.g. http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/

Answer (score 1):

My son (a tech nut) uses [Allok Media Converter](http://www.alloksoft.com/mpeg4_converter.htm) and I concur, it is fantastic.  It pretty much converts anything to anything.  I looked and found it does convert to 3GPP.  It is very easy to use and simply just works.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html). It has a good interface, IMHO. You could also try [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/builds/) (address leading to Windows builds) which converts to almost everything. It's very easy to use if you need basic things.

For example to convert a video to 3gp you just do: ffmpeg.exe -i infile.ext outfile.3gp. It tries to take the best settings (same as the source) and converts the video.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest software I've found to do this is [Convert 3gp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/convert3gp/) (I've used this to convert to PSP mp4 in the past)